# Script that will graph the polar equation r=2+3sin*theta for 0:theta:2*pi

Tags: matlab

How to write a Matlab: script that will graph the polar equation r=2+3sin*theta for 0:theta:2*pi.  If someone could please show me how to write a script for this I would appreciate it very much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please do 'help polar'.  There is an example similar to what you are looking for.